# Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to create Scrapy-app, when the app execute the function 'parse' it goes well(status=200), but when it call 'parse_phone' it can't get that url and logs with the errors.
When i execute 'scrapy shell 'url that is in parse_phone' it executes without problems. 
Can anyone answer what is solution?

```
class DeviceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'device'
start_urls = [
    'https://www.gsmarena.com/makers.php3',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css('.st-text a::attr(href)'):
        time.sleep(random.randint(30,50))
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_phones)

def parse_phones(self, response):
    for href in response.css('#review-body a::attr(href)'):
        time.sleep(random.randint(30,50))
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_device_info)

    next_page = response.css('.pages-next::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        time.sleep(random.randint(30,50))
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_phones)

def parse_device_info(self, response):
    price = response.css('td[data-spec=price]::text').get()()
    models = response.css('td[data-spec=models]::text').get(
    name = response.css('.specs-phone-name-title::text').get)
    Object.objects.create(name='werw')
    if models:
        models = models.split(', ')
    else: 
        models = ['{}'.format(name)]
    launch = response.css('td[data-spec=year]::text').get()
    if launch:
        launch = launch.split(', ')
        obj = Object.objects.create(name=name, launch=datetime.date(launch[0], datetime.datetime.strptime(launch[1][:3]).month, 1))
    else:
        obj = Object.objects.create(name=name)
    for m in models:
        item = Item.objects.create(obj=obj, name=m)
        if price:
            if 'euro' in p.lower():
                Attr.objects.create(item=item, price=Money(float(p.split(' ')[1]), 'EUR'))
            else:
                price = price.split(' / ') 
                price = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\u2009', ''),price))
                for p in prices:
                    price_currency = p[0]
                    price_amount = float(p.split('{}'.format(p[0]))[1])
                    bank_symbols_currency = ''
                    if price_currency == '$':
                        bank_symbols_currency = 'USD'
                    elif price_currency == '€':
                        bank_symbols_currency = 'EUR'
                    elif price_currency == '£':
                        bank_symbols_currency = 'GBP'
                    elif price_currency == '₹':
                        bank_symbols_currency = 'INR'
                    if bank_symbols_currency:
                        Attr.objects.create(item=item, price=Money(price_amount, bank_symbols_currency))
```

I tried with User-agent but it doesn't change the situation.

Comment: What are sleeps for ?

Comment: I think I got it, it's because you will be blocked if request too frequently. what status code you get and what is the error?